# Find unmatched records code

Tags: ms-access

Please verify the below code which was build to find unmatched values between two table in MS access ( as there is run-time error 3075 in query expression Count(table1.Inv_No])'

Public Sub subCreateRowDiff()

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim lngCount As Long

Const TEMP_TABLE As String = "tblNoMatch"

strSQL = "SELECT table1.[Inv_No], table1.[Amt], Count(table1.Inv_No]) As Expr1 GROUP BY table1.[Inv_No], table1.[Amt];"
Set db = CurrentDb

'remove all records
db.Execute "DELETE " & TEMP_TABLE & ".* FROM " & TEMP_TABLE & ";"
'open table1
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "table1", "table2")
'open table2
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
'check for difference
With rs1
    If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then .MoveFirst
    While Not .EOF
        lngCount = .Fields(2).Value 'the count field
        'find matching record in table2
        rs2.FindFirst "[Inv_No] = " & .Fields(0) & " AND [Amt] = " & .Fields(1).Value
        If rs2.NoMatch Then
            'save this record as many times (lngCount)
            While lngCount <> 0
                db.Execute "Insert Into " & TEMP_TABLE & "(Inv_No, Amt) " & _
                            "Values(" & .Fields(0).Value & ", " & .Fields(1) & ");"
                lngCount = lngCount - 1
            Wend
        Else
            ' there is a match
            ' check the difference
            If .Fields(2).Value > rs2.Fields(2).Value Then
                lngCount = .Fields(2).Value - rs2.Fields(2).Value
            Else
                lngCount = rs2.Fields(2).Value - .Fields(2).Value
            End If
            While lngCount <> 0
                db.Execute "Insert Into " & TEMP_TABLE & "(Inv_No, Amt) " & _
                            "Values(" & .Fields(0).Value & ", " & .Fields(1) & ");"
                lngCount = lngCount - 1
            Wend
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Wend
End With

' now use table2 as reference
With rs2
    If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then .MoveFirst
    While Not .EOF
        lngCount = .Fields(2).Value 'the count field
        'find matching record in table1
        rs1.FindFirst "[Inv_No] = " & .Fields(0) & " AND [Amt] = " & .Fields(1).Value
        If rs1.NoMatch Then
            'save this record as many times (lngCount)
            While lngCount <> 0
                db.Execute "Insert Into " & TEMP_TABLE & "(Inv_No, Amt) " & _
                            "Values(" & .Fields(0).Value & ", " & .Fields(1) & ");"
                lngCount = lngCount - 1
            Wend
        Else
            ' we already did this before
            ' so no need
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Wend
End With
rs1.Close: Set rs1 = Nothing
rs2.Close: Set rs2 = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Missing a left bracket [. No brackets are needed in this SQL statement because table and field names do not have spaces.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean please amend the code and send again for me

Comment: Missing left bracket in: Count(table1.Inv_No]) - or just remove all the [ and ] from the SQL statement.